# Accessing private variable outside the method in which it is assigned

Tags: android, android-layout, final, runnable

I've used `Runnable` to find height of the Status bar and it's giving correct output.

But how do I access **StatusBarHeight** outside the `run()` method of `Runnable`?

Here is my piece of code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

        final Rect rectgle = new Rect();
        final Window window = getWindow();

        main.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
                int StatusBarHeight = rectgle.top;
                int contentViewTop = window.findViewById(
                        Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
                int TitleBarHeight = contentViewTop - StatusBarHeight;

                Log.i("ScreenDemo", "StatusBar Height= " + StatusBarHeight
                        + " , TitleBar Height = " + TitleBarHeight);
            }
        });
}
```

P.S. : If I write the code within `run()` directly in `onCreate()`, it returns me **0** as UI has not rendered yet.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `StatusBarHeight` 's scope is local to the block within, if you want to access it from onCreate() method, then you need to declare it as following way,

```
private static int StatusBarHeight;  // class level declaration

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

        final Rect rectgle = new Rect();
        final Window window = getWindow();

        main.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
                StatusBarHeight = rectgle.top;
                int contentViewTop = window.findViewById(
                        Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
                int TitleBarHeight = contentViewTop - StatusBarHeight;

                Log.i("ScreenDemo", "StatusBar Height= " + StatusBarHeight
                        + " , TitleBar Height = " + TitleBarHeight);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: `private static` is a class variable declaration. That isn't really nevessary here (nor is it a good idea). OP just needs a member variable.

Comment: static declaration is necessary when you are dealing with runnable interface or Thread class

Comment: @Lucifer Your statement above "static declaration is necessary..." is not true. It works perfectly fine using an instance variable.

Comment: @DavidWasser it may work fine, but won't give perfect result while you are working with Thread or Runnable Interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your variable as a private member variable in your class so that you can access it outside the `Runnable`. Like this:

```
private int statusBarHeight; // member variable available to all methods in the class

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
    final RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    final Rect rectgle = new Rect();
    final Window window = getWindow();
    main.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
            statusBarHeight = rectgle.top;
            int contentViewTop = window.findViewById(
                     Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
            int titleBarHeight = contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;
            Log.i("ScreenDemo", "StatusBar Height= " + statusBarHeight
                     + " , TitleBar Height = " + titleBarHeight);
        }
    });
}
```

**NOTE:**  I've changed the names of your variables from `StatusBarHeight` to `statusBarHeight` and from `TitleBarHeight` to `titleBarHeight`. Please remember to use initial lowercase names for variables. Java naming conventions use initial lowercase variable names and initial uppercase for class names.